# Multiple records inserting into MySql from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

I think I've got a tiny mistake in my code so when I try to add two records to MySQL database it adds them both, but at the moment its only adding the second row that should be inputted. SO for example I have two RefTitle fields, two RefSurname fields and so on!
Some PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(empty($err)) {
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
$RefTitle = $_POST['RefTitle'][$i];
$RefSurname = $_POST['RefSurname'][$i];
$RefForenames = $_POST['RefForenames'][$i];
$RefInstitute = $_POST['RefInstitute'][$i];
$RefEmail = $_POST['RefEmail'][$i];
$RefTelephone = $_POST['RefTelephone'][$i];
$EmailOK = $_POST['EmailOK'][$i];

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `referees`
(`RefTitle`,`RefSurname`,`RefForenames`,`RefInstitute`, `RefEmail`,    
`RefTelephone`,`EmailOK`)
VALUES

('$RefTitle','$RefSurname','$RefForenames','$RefInstitute','$RefEmail',    
'$RefTelephone','$EmailOK'
)
"; ?>
```

I have the [] after each name field in my html form.
Thanks

Comment: where are you running `mysql_query`

Comment: Where are you calling `mysql_query()`? Inside the loop or outside? Also, this is vulnerable to SQL injection. escape all `$_POST` vars with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Thanks guys, I was running it outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening.

In the loop, you're adding the current query to a string, overwriting the previous query. After the loop ends, you run `mysql_query` but this will only run on the last query generated by the loop.

You have two ways to fix this:

1. Execute the query within the loop on every iteration. Pseudo code:

   for ($i = 1 to 100)
   {
   $query = //build your query;

   mysql_query($query);

   }
2. Alternatively, **(and the better way)** is to use a value list in your insert statement.

An insert with a list of values looks like this

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)
```

So, (pseudo code again)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ";
for ($i = 1 to 100)
{
  $query .= " ("; 
  $query .= "" //comma seperate the values of the current iteration
  $query .= "),";
}
```

//after loop ends, remove the trailing extraneous comma

// execute the entire query at once

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You can insert in one statement more records for the same table. that's more efficient: INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);